# Excel VBA - using SELECT CASE but now need an array

Tags: excel, vba

I've currently got the code below.  There can only currently be seven values for "ins" and so the code suffices, however as of next month I have been told that there will be over 900 values!

I assume that rather than writing another 900 case statements I could use an array of some sort.  Can anyone give me a nudge in the right direction?

```
Private Sub test()
Dim i As Long
Dim lr As Long
Dim ins As String

lr = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 6 To lr
Select Case Cells(i, 20)
    Case Is = "" 
        ins = Mid(Cells(i, 11), 14, 2)
            Select Case Cells(i, 10)
                Case "Inx", "ComInx"
                     Select Case Cells(i, 9)
                         Case "EINX"
                              Select Case ins
                                  Case "LD"
                                      Cells(i, 9).Value = "SR"
                                  Case "GP"
                                      Cells(i, 9).Value = "GAMA"
                                  Case "AV"
                                      Cells(i, 9).Value = "NU"
                                  Case "AX"
                                      Cells(i, 9).Value = "AXC"
                                  Case "MZ"
                                      Cells(i, 9).Value = "MZE"
                                  Case "AD"
                                      Cells(i, 9).Value = "AGD"
                                  Case "AG"
                                      Cells(i, 9).Value = "AG"
                              End Select
                     End Select
            End Select
End Select
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: there are arrays, collections, dictionaries, own types, etc.. research!

Comment: I suggest you use a lookup table stored in a range-hardcoding the values would be a maintenance nightmare

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use a dictionary object for this. Here is a proof-of-concept based on your lines:

```
Private Sub test()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim ins As String        
    Dim rngCases As Range, rngCases2 As Range, rngCase As Range
    Dim dicCases As Dictionary

    lr = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    ' rngCases stores the possible values of ins
    ' Here I assume they are stored in col 40
    Set rngCases = Range(Cells(6, 40), Cells(lr, 40))

    ' rngCases2 stores the values you want to map for each value of ins.
    ' Here I assume they are stored in col 41
    ' No of entries = No of entries of rngCases
    Set rngCases2 = Range(Cells(6, 41), Cells(lr, 41))
    Set dicCases = New Dictionary

    For Each rngCase In rngCases
        If Not dicCases.Exists(rngCase.Value) Then
            dicCases.Add Key:=rngCase.Value, Item:=rngCases2.Value
        End If
    Next rngCase

    For i = 6 To lr
    Select Case Cells(i, 20)
        Case Is = ""
            ins = Mid(Cells(i, 11), 14, 2)
                Select Case Cells(i, 10)
                    Case "Inx", "ComInx"
                         Select Case Cells(i, 9)
                             Case "EINX"
                                ' We simply need to refer to the mapped value of ins
                                 If dicCases.Exists(ins) then
                                     Cells(i, 9) = dicCases.Item(ins)
                                 Else
                                     ' Throw an error or do something here
                                 End If
                         End Select
                End Select
    End Select
    Next

End Sub
```

To enable the `Dictionary`, go to `Tools->References` and select `Microsoft Scripting Runtime`.

I hope this gets you started!